# Windows Phone 8.1, binding to AppBarButton not rendering

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, winrt-xaml

I'm displaying a string of several characters in an `AppBarButton` in a Windows Phone application. The string consists of the *Segoe UI Symbol* character "attach" (*\uE16C*) and a the number of items the user has already attached.

I've binded the *AppBarButton*'s Icon property to a the number of items that have been attached, which is converted to a `FontIcon`.

```
<AppBarButton Icon="{Binding ItemCount, Converter={StaticResource IntToFontIconConverter}}"/>
```

However, for some reason the `AppBarButton` doesn't seem to always re-render when the FontIcon changes. I've vertified that the binding is updated and the `AppBarButtons` FontIcon changes, but it's not reflected on the phone's screen.

Is there someway to force the button to re-render when the `FontIcon` changes?

Answer (score 0):

Check below code it might solve your problem

```
<AppBarButton Label="BitmapIcon" Click="AppBarButton_Click">
<AppBarButton.Icon>
    <BitmapIcon UriSource="ms-appx:///Assets/globe.png"/>
</AppBarButton.Icon>
```

find more details on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj662743.aspx